# Fill a data frame with increasing date objects in R

Tags: r, loops, date, for-loop

I can't seem to figure the following out.

I have a data frame with 398 rows and 16 variables. I want to add a date variable. I know that for each row the date increases by a week and starts with 2010-01-01. I've tried the following:

```
date <- ymd("2010-01-01")
df <- as.data.frame(c(1:nrow(data), 1))
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  date <- date + 7
  df[i,] <- as.Date(date)
}
```

I then want to bind it to my data-frame. However, the values inside df are non-dates. If I perform the date +7 calculation it works (e.g. once it goes to 2010-01-08), but if I assign it to the df it turns into weird numerical values.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Also, in addition to @Shaun Wilkinson's comment about names, please indicate the libraries you are using (here, e.g. `lubridate`) and provide all data necessary so that we can essentially just copy-paste your code. For instance, `data` is missing from your code. Questions get really fast answers if we can just copy-paste your code and everything else but the main problem works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
library(lubridate)
date <- ymd("2010-01-01")

df <- data.frame(ind = 1:5)
df$dates <- seq.Date(from = date, length.out = nrow(df), by = 7) 
# note that `by = "1 week"` would also work, if you prefer more readable code.
df
  ind      dates
1   1 2010-01-01
2   2 2010-01-08
3   3 2010-01-15
4   4 2010-01-22
5   5 2010-01-29
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df$date <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = 7, length.out = 398)
```

also try to get in the habit of not calling your variables names that are already being used by functions such as `data` and `date`.